# Google calendar sync has stopped working

Tags: thunderbird, calendar, google-sync

I set up Google Calendar to sync with Lightning in Thunderbird. It has worked well for the last few weeks. It has now suddenly stopped working. I have checked the CalDAV addresses and they are all still ok. I do not know if my recent addition of syncing my new Android phone with the Google Calendar has anything to do with it, or just a coincidence.

When Thunderbird tries to sync, it asks for the username and password. I enter these for the Google Calendar, and end up in a continuous circle.

Comment: You mean, it keeps asking you for the password? What system are you using? Can you log-in over web normally? Is there any error which appears? If you using Linux, can you run Thunderbird from the Terminal and see if there are any errors?

Comment: Yes, it continually asks to enter the user name and password. I am currently logged into Win7, can give Ubuntu a go when I am able to reset my system (I have processes running I cannot interrupt). I can log into Google Calendar via the web interface with no problem. I do not get any error messages - just keeps asking to confirm the login.

Comment: Check the Thunderbird error log file, see: https://wiki.mozilla.org/MailNews:Logging#Windows and paste the errors. Otherwise it's just a guessing.

Comment: 0[1a0f140]: autosync paused

Comment: Which version of Thunderbird do you have?

Comment: And please as well generate another log file (more detailed) as stated in the answer.

Comment: I am running Thunderbird 14.0. Using the syntax below, I get the output '0[e0f140]: autosync paused'. I cannot be more detailed than that as that is all the output file contains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FWIW: for the past few days I've been getting semi-frequent (3-4 times per day) occurrences of OS X Calendar/iCal and a third-party product, Fantastical, throwing errors that my password was not accepted. The folks at Flexibits (Fantastical) inform me that they're seeing a wave of similar reports.

So, it would *appear* that something's wrong on Google's end. I found this thread when search for other reports of the problem.

Comment: Opened Thunderbird today with no errors. Must have been Google! I'll blame them anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem after setting up my new Android phone. In my case, I think the problem was related to the fact that I had to add a Gmail account to my Google account to be able to use my android device, instead of using the non-Google address as login that I used before to setup the calendar. 
My username for accessing the calendar was therefore changed as a result of this process (note that it is still the same account). 
I can login with my new (Gmail) username, but Thunderbird says that calendar is temporarily unavailable.

The solution was to replace the username in my CALDAV address:

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/[old non-google email adress username]/events
```

with

```
https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/[gmail address]/events
```

After that it worked and I could also see my old events added under the previous user name again.

P.S. I couldn't directly change the CALDAV address, but I had to add a new calendar and remove the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check if you the latest version of Thunderbird?

Here is how you should run Thunderbird to generate the log file specifically for synchronization issues:

```
c:\>set NSPR_LOG_MODULES=ImapAutoSync:4
c:\>set NSPR_LOG_FILE=c:\LogFile.log
c:\>"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Thunderbird\thunderbird.exe"
```

Possibly this could be one of the following bugs:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=589310

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=533257